# Fetch request template - fetch all objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am getting started with fetch request templates, so will try my best to explain.please ask if need more details.

I have created a fetch request template:
[image]

and Trying to print all the objects in a method below:

```
 - (void)printOfflineActivities 
{
    EntityManager* entityManager = [[EntityManager alloc] init];
    ActivityFetcher *activityFetcher = [[ActivityFetcher alloc] initWithEntityManager:entityManager];
    Activity *activity = [activityFetcher activitiesOffline:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

    NSLog(@"printing..%@",activity.name);
}
```

Code for activitiesOffline is

```
- (Activity*)activitiesOffline:(NSNumber*)offline 
{
    NSDictionary* variables = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:offline forKey:OfflineTemplatePlaceholder];
    NSFetchRequest* request = [entityManager fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:ActivityOffline substitutionVariables:variables];
    Activity* activity = [entityManager entityForFetchRequest:request];

    return activity;
}
```

But this prints out only last value. I am not sure how to print all the activities that satisfies the condition/expression?

Answer (score 1):

1. Fetch request template should look like (**Variables are denoted with a $ (for example $VARIABLE_NAME)**):
   [image]
2. Retrieve necessary fetch request from the model like below:

   ```
   NSFetchRequest* request = [self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:@"ActivityOffline" substitutionVariables:@{@"ANY_VARIABLE_NAME":offline}];
   ```

Comment: Thanks. (1) Its a BOOL variable and allows me to use == TRUE or == 1. (2) except for managedObjectContext, how is the NSFetchRequest different from request in my code?

Comment: As I understand you are trying to use fetch request template with substitution variables. It means that on runtime in one moment you may want to fetch items that match predicate `offline == YES` and second time fetch items matching `offline == NO`. Am I wrong?

Comment: I just want to fetch items matching offline == YES.

Comment: also, I am able to fetch last item in the list which satisfies offline == YES. But I want to print all the items.

Comment: Then you do not need to pass variables in line `[entityManager fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:ActivityOffline substitutionVariables:variables];`. That is why I've understood you incorrectly.

Comment: Oh. you are right. i changed that now. now only question remaining is to print all the items. currently I'm printing     NSLog(@"printing..%@",activity.name); to print all the fetched items should i put them in an array and print it or is there any direct way to do this?

Comment: Put items into array, then force items faulting by using for example `[itemsArray valueForKey:@"name"]` and then log `NSLog(@"printing items ..%@",itemsArray);`